# Is the word "queer" an accepted and polite word for lesbian?

Tags: word-usage, offensive-language, politeness, political-correctness, sexual-minorities

I was reading an article on the promulgation of the dental dam as a means of preventing sexually transmitted disease. [Article here](http://www.theverge.com/2014/3/20/5522106/the-sexual-history-of-the-dental-dam). The author of the article [Arielle Duhaime-Ross](http://www.arielleduhaimeross.com) consistently refers to lesbian women as "queer women".

Up until now, it had been my understanding that this term was a pejorative and insulting to homosexuals. That it implies their choice of lifestyle to be strange and aberrant.  So, I was rather surprised to see this term being bandied about in a reasonably respectable online tech and lifestyle reporting website.

Shows like "Queer Eye for the Straight Guy" notwithstanding, it just didn't strike me as proper in the format.

Ms. Duhaime-Ross does not have a biography that I could find on her website. I couldn't discern if she, herself, is a lesbian and is using a preferred nomenclature. Or, if it is a term only used amongst "members of the club" similar to African American usage of the n-word.

I decided to post it here, hoping to better understand the protocol about the term.  My motivation is to be able to address people as they *wish* to be addressed.

Comment: ["Less confrontational terms that attempt to reunite the interests of lesbian, gay, bisexual, and transgender people also became prominent, including various acronyms like LGBT, **LGBTQ**, and LGBTI, where the Q and I stand for queer or questioning and intersex, respectively."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBTQ_social_movements) FWIW, many gays I've known commonly self-identify as *queer*; it seems to be a stronger way of "putting it out there" than *gay* is. But I would hesitate to call someone *queer* myself.

Comment: @Robusto I've heard it used in that way, too. But, always wishing to be respectful in addressing people as they wish to be addressed:  I figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Important to note here is that "queer women" in this context does *not* mean "lesbian". It is explicitly defined as "women that have sex with women". This includes bisexual and trans* women who may not themselves identify as "lesbian". "Queer", in this usage, is meant to be a more inclusive term than "lesbian".

In the LGBTQ/QUILTBAG community (of which I am a member), "queer" is generally used as an umbrella term to encompass the broad scope of sexuality, gender identity, and gender presentation that falls outside the heterosexual/cisgender "mainstream". That seems to be the purpose of its use in the article.

Comment: Thanks!  That insight is very helpful. So, is this a preferred way of saying women who have sex with other women??

Comment: Also, I've not seen QUILTBAG before. What is it an acronym for?

Comment: @DavidM For the purpose of the article, yes, because that's how the author defines its use. In general, though, "queer women" can have the broader meaning of "non-heterosexual and/or non-cisgender individuals that identify as women".

Comment: @DavidM QUILTBAG = Queer/Questioning, Unknown/Undefined. Intersex, Lesbian, Transgender/Transsexual, Bisexual, Asexual/Androgynous, Gay/Genderqueer

Comment: Thanks, again!  I hope my question was received as being a respectful inquiry. I went out of my way to try.

Comment: This is a very good answer, I'll just add that "QUILTBAG" is sometimes used a little bit tongue in cheek, as the mentality is about recognizing that not everyone's biology/life fits into a neat little box, nor should they.  Also, 'Queer', like a lot of reclaimed epithets, should be used by straight people towards others only with great caution and care.

Comment: I believe it's a members-only word, a word *we* can use as casually as we like, but the *not-we* can't use at all, unless *we* give them permission to use it in certain carefully controlled circumstances. The appropriate way for the *not-we* to respond is to refuse to use the word in any circumstances.

Comment: @Terpsichore Attitudes on that vary wildly. I personally don't like the idea of "banning" a word, and I have no problem with cishet people who use it with the proper connotation and understanding. And when they don't, it just saves me the trouble of pretending to care about their opinion.

Comment: @Roger - declining to use a word is not the same thing as banning it; you aren't imposing your choices on anyone else.

Comment: @Terpsichore It is when you say "the *not-we* can't use [it] at all, unless *we* give them permission". That's dictating who can and can't use a word and under which circumstances, which I don't agree with. Sometimes, "queer" is the most appropriate and succinct word for the situation (ex. Queer Studies, as noted in comments elsewhere). Now, I agree that people *should* refuse to use a charged word if they can't use it respectfully and conscientiously, but that doesn't mean they always *will* refuse.

Comment: @Roger - when I wrote the quoted words, I was being satirical and speaking in the voice of those who would dictate when and how a word can be used, while reserving for themselves the right to use it in any casual way they choose. I do not belong to any such group, and do not believe there are any special privileges that groups can claim for themselves in the use of language, while denying those privileges to those outside the group. I hope that clears it up.

Comment: @Terpsichore Thanks for that. I guess my satire sensor (Poe-dar?) is fritzy today. I blame lack of sleep.

Comment: Quiltbag is a funny word. That is all.

Answer (score 3):

The word has been "reclaimed" by *some* LGBTQ folks as their own word to describe their identities. The distinction between the pejorative use and the "reclaimed" use is largely a matter of the tone of the text in which the word is used. When in doubt, don't use it.

Comment: That is what I had figured. But, it seemed odd in a publication. You wouldn't typically see an informative article written by an African American using the n-word so casually.

Comment: I am old enough to remember when males homosexuals were described quite openly as 'queer'. But oddly, in the context of this question, I don't remember it being applied to lesbians.

Comment: There are slight differences in the usages. In *Queer Studies*, which is a sub-discipline of sociology that studies LGBTQ contributions to society, this is a far more normal usage than the `n-word` would be in African-American Studies, for instance.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This originates from the Yorkshire adage 'There's nowt so queer as folk'. It is spoken when people, as they frequently do, behave in a thoroughly illogical way, perhaps against their own best interests. Just because it is no longer acceptable to describe homosexuals as 'queer' doesn't mean there is a complete embargo on the word in all contexts.

Comment: The key word in this answer is *some*. Some, not all. There are a lot of LGBT people—especially but not exclusively older—who have no truck with "reclaiming" and greatly take exception to being described using a word that has its historical roots as a fairly harsh insult.

Source: personal experience as a gay man who does not like being called 'queer' and will tell people explicitly to *not* call me 'queer'.